# displaying an error in a success function angular js

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

how do i display/log an error that a json page returns in a success function?

i have the following out put in my json page when there is no error

```
{"success":1,"error":"","recordcount":"1","fields":["Column1","Column2","Column3"],"data":[{"Column1":"0","Column2":"2015-03-26T00:00:00","Column3":""} ]}
```

if an error had to occur

```
{"success":0,"error":" violation error","recordcount":"0","fields":[],"data":[ ]}
```

if there is no error it will display the self.show message,how ever when an error is returned it must console.log or show me the exact error on the webpage
function

```
  Get(self.$http,
            {
                url: Savedata,
                params: params,
                success: function (data)
                {

                    if (self.Save = data.data) {


                        self.Show = " saved."
                    }
                    else {
                        self.show = " ";
                    }
                    if (self.Save = data.error)
                    {
                        self.test= error //it should display the error from my json page                        }

                }
            }).error(function ()

            {

            });
```

Comment: your comparision condition should be proper `if (self.Save == data.error)
                    {
                        self.test= error //it should display the error from my json page                        }

                }` should always use `==` or `===`

Comment: i tried that self.save==data.error doesnt work

Comment: could you create a problem with plunkr/fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the structure was wrong

```
 success: function (data)
            {

                if (self.Save = data.data) {
                 self.Show = " saved."
                }
                else if(self.save==null)
                 {
                   self.show=data.error;
                 }

            }
        }).error(function ()
```